# Why is the Firebase iOS SDK CocoaPod over 70 MB?

Tags: firebase, cocoapods

After running `pod install` for the Firebase iOS CocoaPod, I noticed that the Firebase pod is over 70MB. Why is this and is there any way to mitigate this?

Comment: By the way, you can see its size in [its CocoaPods page](https://cocoapods.org/?q=firebase).

Comment: This is an interesting question that I wanted to test. I created a brand new swift project in Xcode, walked through the steps to install Firebase via cocoapods and created a quick test app to ensure everything was installed (write to firebase, read from firebase) The entire project; headers, firebase, support files etc is 5.1Mb for 66 files.

Answer (score 0):

The main Firebase pod is so big as it contains all the parts for every part of Firebase. One of the solutions I've had is to only use the parts needed, rather than just

```
pod Firebase
```

you can have

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
```